# Are the iPhone media playback control window available to other applications?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

what is the transparent modal window that has the playback controls in the music player (iPod) of the iPhone? how can i use it in my app?

Comment: actually I just want to use the semi-transparent box. not the controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access and control the iPod playback through `[MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer]`, but beside `MPVolumeView` there a no built-in controls you can display in your app. You would have to design your own custom view.